# Advice on collection schema for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am developing a little league app for my son's league as a "weekend project" and as a way to learn mongodb.  I'm struggling with the best way to setup the schema in MongoDB.  My biggest hangup is on whether or not I should replicate some of the data.  Here's my first stab at the schema

Collection - 
Player

```
    { "firstname": "Test",
     "lastname" : "Player",
     "street":"123 Lamar",
      "city": "Austin",
      "state":"TX" ,
      "zip": "78701",
     "littleleagueid": "123",
     "league":"minors",
     "team":"Rangers",
     parents : 
    [ {
    "firstname": "Bob",
    "lastname": "Player",
    "relationship": "father",
    "street":"123 Lamar",
    "city": "Austin",
     "state":"TX",
    "zip": "78701"
    },
    {
    "firstname": "Sally",
    "lastname": "Player",
    "relationship": "stepmother", 
    "street":"123 Lamar",
    "city": "Austin",
    "state":"TX",
    "zip": "78701"
    },
    {
    "firstname": "Sue",
    "lastname": "Explayer",
    "relationship": "mother",
    "street":"456 Congress",
    "city": "Austin",
    "state":"TX",
    "zip": "78761"}
     ]
```

}

My biggest question is should I embed the parents into the kids collection or should they be separated to into their own collection?  The address is being repeated multiple times. This might be the best method but in a SQL environment I would have just pulled this into its own table.

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to figure out what your read and write patterns will be - without knowing how application will be using the data it's impossible to say what the best schema would be.

Comment: In this case you have relational data - why are you using mongodb? I'm guessing the volume isn't going to be so huge that you can't use SQL here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need fast queries:
I think your schema is more or less Ok.

If you need fast updates:
I would instead refer to the parents using their _id to convert player collection into people collection. In this way if parents change you only update one document and not as many as players having this parent.

Keep in mind that, even if you need fast queries, this is not very maintainable because you may have, as you say, duplicate data and this can lead to data inconsistencies.